# How can i add any data to an existing url in flutter which is not firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the endpoint of the url dynamically

```
ex:
https:// something.co/user/topic/id

if user click on the topic1 in the topic list, Then
topic1 : 12345, https:// something.co/user/topic/123456

if clicked on topic 2
topic : 678910, https:// something.co/user/topic/678910
```

Note: This is for an app not for web.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll`:

```
    final original = 'https://something.co/user/topic/id';
    final find = 'id';
    final replaceWith = '12345';
    final newString = original.replaceAll(find, replaceWith);
```

Comment: I want to change it dynamically and both are in differnet class